# How to make an event (js) work with an input radio that is created by a "for" (php)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to put an onclick="myfunction()" or any event that will bring the value of the Radio Input. The value would need to be display as soon as its chosen with ajax. Same with all the other values.  The problem is that the Radio Input is displayed by a "for" so that it displays as many times as there is data (colors in this case) in the api. What should I do?

```
$('input:radio[name=color]').change(function()
```

---

This kind of works, but only in the html file, not the .js file. In addition, it doesn't correctly get me the other values (position & alto, etc..)

### PHP:

```
for ($quantity=0;$quantity<$numberofcolors;$quantity++)
{
$vartest=$data[$testcontador]["Colores"][$quantity];
echo '<div class="hiddenradio"><label><input type="radio" id="color" required class="stored" name="color" value="'.$vartest.'" />
<img style="border: 2px solid black; width: 50px;margin:5px;" src="../imagenes/'.  $vartest.'.png"/> '.$vartest.'</label></div>
';
//this displays all color icons.
}
echo '<label for="name">Alto: </label>
<span>
  <input type="number" id="alto" min="'.$altomin.'" max="'.$altomax.'" onkeyup="myfunction()" name="alto" value="'.$altomin.'" class="required" role="input" aria-required="true" required/>
</span>';
```

---

### JS:

```
 function myfunction() {
  var posit = document.getElementById("position").value;
  var alto = document.getElementById("alto").value;
$.ajax({
     url: "../vista/gethint.php",
     type: "GET",
     data: {altojs: alto,positjs:posit},
     success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("icard3").innerHTML = data;
     }
  });
}
```

---

```
 var alto = document.getElementById("alto").value;
```

I want something like this but for the radio input so it's simpler to get the value. I'm new at this stuff...

Comment: You'd need to attach the listener to the body, then target the element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Give all of the elements that you want to behave the same way the same class.  Then bind the event handler to the class.  Also, don't assign a static element ID within a loop (such as `id="color"`).  All elements must have unique IDs (or no ID)

Comment: ...and use the "checked" property to pick the right one... const radioButtons = document.querySelector(".classOnYourRadioButtons"); for(let i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++){ if(radioButtons[i].checked){ alert(radioButtons[i].value); }}

Comment: Give them a `class="stored color"` instead of equal `id`s. Use array names `name=color[$quantity]`. Do not echo HTML, write plain HTML closing PHP tags.

Comment: I was able to fix it using this: 
  var radioButTrat = document.getElementsByName("color");

  for (var i=0; i<radioButTrat.length; i++) {

  if (radioButTrat[i].checked == true) {